# What is the sense of permitting the user to use no passwords longer than xx chars?

Tags: database, security, passwords, usability

It's more like a usability question or maybe database, or even maybe security (consider injection attacks) but what is the sense of permitting the user's password to a be not longer than xx chars? It does not make any sense to me, because longer passwords are mostly considered better and even harder to crack, and some users use password safes, so the password length should not matter.

I understand that passwords with more than 20 chars are hardly to remember, but if you use diceware or password safe you don't have any problem with that. I really cant understand why there are sites that say "your password need to be between 5 and 8 chars"...

also should the password saved as hash, so the length of the field in the database is fixed, so where is the problem?

I think that most of the sites where the password is has to be a fixed length are not even using any hashing method.

Comment: there is no sense to it, also forcing users to add special characters or numbers is a false safety illusion. Since you understand this, you can start making the world better by allowing users to have a password between 1 and 255 chars and any char goes. :)

Comment: in my programms you probaly could insert a whole book as password and it would work :D but there are so many sites, e.g. paypal has 20 chars max, so somebody probably had thoughts about something... preventing any injection attacks maybe?

Comment: but if the password is hashed there is a theoretical chance that the correct abstract of the same book as the one you use as a password, will give me access as well! :D I doubt it's a bigger security hole than having a limit on password length in the first place though.

Comment: if you are using not collision free hashing algorithm, but the chance that this happens is very rare. i know for md5 its possible but i dont think that anyone will make that, because rainbow tables are very much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see an upper limit for your choice of a password, you can guess that they want to store it un-hashed. And that's really bad.

Passwords are 'the longer the better' and they should also be composed of letters from an alphabet as big as possible. The differences are quite well explained here: https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

Comment: yes but paypal?? why the heck they should store them unencrypted?

Comment: Encryption and hashing are two different things. Hashing is one-way. They would not be able to restore your password from the hash. And that is important because then your password cannot leak to third parties in case their data 'gets lost'.
If paypal is hashing the password, then there is no need to restrict the length. If the do it anyway (what I don't know) it's just stupid.